# getting code for css and javascript in a textarea (sort of like js bin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Hello I am still a beginner in j query. I am trying to recreate something like js bin to improve my programming in j query. I am already familiar with getting the inner HTML and setting it to any value i want, But i have no idea in adding CSS and JavaScript based on the input of the user. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same thing, except that you create `style` and `script` elements that you assign your text to as HTML. Then add these elements to the document.

<sub>(Also, don't use jQuery)</sub>

Comment: what is the reason why i shouldn't use jQuery?

Comment: It encourages writing bad code, a lot of imperative DOM manipulation, with strings being  parsed to HTML. Also, all its primary functions have been superseded by now standardized APIs.